# How to prepare custom training data for Donut (Document Understanding Transformer)?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I want to train Hugging Face's Donut (Document Understanding Transformer) but I need help in creating the training data.

Donut github: https://github.com/clovaai/donut

Donut official documentation: https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/model_doc/donut

If anybody has already created and trained the model, kindly help.

Comment: I have gone through the link. It tells how to train the model on some already available datasets on huggingface. However, it doesn't tell how to create ground truth for a custom dataset.
Thanks for your comment though.

Comment: Please check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75578739/5660086), hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

please visit roboflow , annotate your images via rob flow annotation tools , than export the file in coco json format , as the model of donut is expecting the input as json file . use script available at hugging face for training the model

Answer (score 0):

Dear Create json files for your data , use some python script that will convert text files into json files , for training donut models it requires json files and images , you need to generate json files for your images , and than pass it to model , the model will eventually learn .