# Pre-training Donut (document understanding transformer)

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I am trying to replicate the pre-training (train from scratch) phase of Donut model (https://github.com/clovaai/donut). In the paper mentioned:

"In the
pre-training phase, Donut learns how to read the texts by predicting the next
words by conditioning jointly on the image and previous text contexts."

What I don't understand is that how the "previous text contexts" is used for the pretraining process while the input of the model is only an image. How I should change the fine-tuning code to be able to pretrain the model?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question, it seems that pre-training is actually the same as fine-tuning. The only difference is that in pre-training you train the model to predict all the text on the document (or, at least up to the max output size).

Since they use MBart as the decoder, it has support for multiple languages. https://github.com/clovaai/donut/blob/master/donut/model.py#L136

However, they only provided fine-tuned models on English or Chinese data.

I wanted to pre-train it on another language and all i had to do is generate some images and json files using their [SynthDoG](https://github.com/clovaai/donut/tree/master/synthdog) , it created train, test and validation folders from a simple text file, i had to change the config and the result is 10k images like this: [image: Image for pretraining]
this is the json for this image:

```
{"file_name": "image_138.jpg", "ground_truth": "{\"gt_parse\": {\"text_sequence\": \"ă \\\"a testat cu succes o rachetă de crozieră tip Zircon în Marea Albă.4 goluriîn 36 de meciuri a adunat Costache pentru CFR Cluj în actuala edițieCea mai mare bază militară a Chin ei dispune de replici ale Turnului Eiffel și clădiril e prezidențiale din TaiwanOdată cu alegerea lui Donald Tru mp în 2016, contra atacul împotriva mla știnii de la Washington a î nceput.Zi neagră pe piaţa criptomo nedelor.Astrele vă recomandă să v ă gândiți mai mult la ceea ce contează cu adevărat. Dar cred că putem avea un minimum de pretenţii chiar şi atunci când suma pe care o pune m la bătaie când cumpărăm o locuinţă este ceva mai mi că.Ele includ lipsa mirosului sau/şi a gustulu i, durere în gât, febră.Cauza probabilă a incen diului a fost stabilita ca fiind coș de fum deteriorat.Se poate să fi găsit ceva re zonabil ca preţ de cumpărat şi să nu ezitaţi s-o faceţi c-o să v-aducă un confort casnic.Iniţiativa îi aparține Conf.Univ.Dr Victor Costache ,șeful secției d e chirurgie cardiovasculară Sf Constantin.Pepenele roşu nu mai trebuie consumat nici de persoanele sănătoase, dacă apar d ureri abdominale, balonare şi gaze instestinale ori afecţiuni ale sistemului digestiv\\\", spune dr.Oamenii președintelui, \\\"vânați\\\" de USR!Săgetătorii, mai ales în prima parte a zilei, manifestă m ai multă înțelegere pentru ceilalți de la care au mari așteptări, astfel încât, spre final de zi, lucrurile se pot l ămuri cu vorbe bune.Contra își cere toți banii! - E dreptul lui să-și ia banii pe ce-a muncit.Glo riile sau Snowball...Demersul, imposibil de dus până la capăt.Un tânăr în vârstă de 19 ani din Franța a prezentat pe ntru a intra într-un spital, unde avea programare, certificatul sanitar al lui Emma nuel Macron, care a ajuns în urmă cu câteva zile să fie distribu it în social media, relatează revista Le Point, citată de News.ro.Nu numai ca s-au redus in cent imetri (dimensiunea 44 are acum masuratorile a ceea ce odinioara era 46), dar moda insas\"}}"}
```

and the json for all images is in metadata.jsonl, don't worry if the words are split, donut at this stage is learning how the letters look like.
Then create a folder `base` inside donut/dataset and paste the 3 folders created by SynthDog.
Copy `donut/config/train_cord.yaml` to `donut/config/base.yaml` change `dataset_name_or_paths` to the new folder you created inside dataset `dataset_name_or_paths: ["dataset/base"]` and change input size to based on your images resolutin (must be multiple of 320), also based on your GPU VRAM, higher res needs more VRAM on GPU, also max_length affects the memory, on a 16GB card i was able to train with this configuration but it was a bit slow:

```
resume_from_checkpoint_path: null # only used for resume_from_checkpoint option in PL
result_path: "./result"
pretrained_model_name_or_path: "naver-clova-ix/donut-base" # loading a pre-trained model (from moldehub or path)
dataset_name_or_paths: ["dataset/base"] # loading datasets (from moldehub or path)
sort_json_key: False # cord dataset is preprocessed, and publicly available at https://huggingface.co/datasets/naver-clova-ix/cord-v2
train_batch_sizes: [1]
val_batch_sizes: [1]
input_size: [1600, 1920] # when the input resolution differs from the pre-training setting, some weights will be newly initialized (but the model training would be okay)
max_length: 700
align_long_axis: False
num_nodes: 1
seed: 2022
lr: 3e-4
warmup_steps: 300 # 800/8*30/10, 10%
num_training_samples_per_epoch: 800
max_epochs: 30
max_steps: -1
num_workers: 8
val_check_interval: 1.0
check_val_every_n_epoch: 10
gradient_clip_val: 1.0
verbose: True
```

You can try with less `max_epochs`, it dependes on how many images you have generates, less images higher epochs..

Run `python train.py --config config/base.yaml --exp_version "base"`

and after some days of waithing you will get your base pretrained_model in `donut/result/base`
Upload the contents of `donut/result/base/base` to huggingface and you'll be able to fine tune on it by setting it to
`pretrained_model_name_or_path: "your_huggingface_user/base"` or just the path to it if you don't upload

Hope it helps, this was my experience with donut... if you have any other questions please ask.

Comment: Oooh I'm not OP but this is exactly what I was looking for! So basically you just have to find or make a "wiki_my_language.txt" and you can start pretraining on any language, sweet! If you want to fine tune, what annotator would you recommend for creating a custom dataset (hopefully one that runs on localhost without registration/data upload)? Do I understand correctly, you can use any JSON structure to contain custom fields, as long as you put everything you want to predict into the "gt_parse" field? Which parameters would you increase first if you had more GPU memory? Thank you!

Comment: you can increase train_batch_sizes, val_batch_sizes,input_size and max_length until you reach 90% VRAM utilization, For annotation you can try https://github.com/allenai/pawls. Yes, you can use any structure, i am worjing now on a table structure where donut will indentify rows and columns values, but if you want to work with less that 5-6 types of documents to extract data from you can use https://github.com/AI4Bharat/DocSim to generate the dataset with random text and fine-tune donut on that

Comment: Thisi is a line from metadata.jsonl for a table image {"file_name":"PMC1064074_table_0.jpg","ground_truth":"{\"gt_parse\":{\"cells\":[{\"row_0_col_0\":\"Kinetic parameter\"},{\"row_0_col_1\":\"ND\"},{\"row_0_col_2\":\"D\"},{\"row_0_col_3\":\"D + dn-RhoA\"},{\"row_0_col_4\":\"D + dn-Rac1\"},{\"row_1_col_0\":\"Vmax\"},{\"row_1_col_1\":\"19.6 ± 0.75\"},{\"row_1_col_2\":\"26.2 ± 0.86*\"},{\"row_1_col_3\":\"31.3 ± 0.88†\"},{\"row_1_col_4\":\"21.6 ± 0.9\"}]}}"}
As you can see you just need to create a structure and donut will look for that text and learn how to extract it from similar documents

Comment: thank you for everything! I'm pre-training it on a new language, with a 4090 it can still barely fit the same config you provided. I'm looking at 40 minute epochs so this should last over a week! One thing I don't understand - I had to port it to PyTorch 2.0 as the earlier version ferom github doesn't support this GPU, however I was initially getting an error about `RuntimeError: It looks like your LightningModule has parameters that were not used in producing the loss returned by training_step`. I changed `find_unused_parameters` to True, but dunno what it means exactly. Do you know?

Comment: This flag results in an extra traversal of the autograd graph every iteration, which can adversely affect performance, but it's not that bad, i was doing 50 minutes / epoch, check your nvidia-smi and if you have unused vram you can try to speed it up by increasing train_batch_sizes or val_batch_sizes or try setting DDPStrategy(find_unused_parameters=True, static_graph=True) to see if you get a speed up.

Comment: @Gabriel maybe a silly question: you explained how to train the model by the command line propt `python train.py --config config/base.yaml --exp_version "base"` how would i trigger a training with code? Is that possible at all?

Comment: Just look at train.py file, you can import it or copy it's content to a new file and create a config  config = Config(args.config) replacing args.config with the config file path and call train(config). Basically all you need to change is from if __name__ == "__main__": to bottom

Comment: @Gabriel Without the flag/extra traversal, the code wouldn't run at all, it'd just give an error. Other than that I've found while pretraining I can increase the nTED-based accuracy score to about 98%, but the F1 score just won't go above 0.25. Checking the model for some predictions shows there's loads of repeat words/repeat phrases. Is that to be expected with the pretraining on SythDOG images, or do I need to experiment some more with hyperparameters? I'm like 2 weeks away from getting the actual dataset so I want to experiment with pretraining until then.

Comment: I had the same problem when using less than 15% warmup_steps and less than 30 epochs, also try to generate images with SythDOG with max max_length characters. i got best results with max_length: 768, input_size: [1600, 1920] and the images generated had around 600-700 chars, also use more than 3k images. Here is the SythDOG config I've used:  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Wyzix33/donut/main/synthdog_config_ro.yaml  just change corpus and use fonts similar to your documents , test with or without background, i found that in my case it's better without

Comment: @Gabriel thank you, I'll try. I'm already doing 10k images generated by SynthDog (8k used for training) and mirrored your Donut config from this post (with reasonable modifications like increasing the warmup steps to be 15%). I think I only tried it with 30 epochs, might increase that. I'll also try mirroring your SynthDOG config. Thank you for coming back and discussing this with me! Oh one more thing. If I'll be using a mixture of documents in 2 languages, do you think it'd make sense to use a single model pretrained on mixed language images, or a separate model for each language?

Comment: This is only valid if the languages have different characters, by default donut works at character level, it already knows "how to read" by including

pretrained_model_name_or_path: "naver-clova-ix/donut-base"

in the config.
You just need to fine tune with text on your specific background and font, or other characters that are not present in English language. So just make sure your corpus contains all characters you want to teach donut to read

Comment: @Gabriel yeah there's special characters in my language but otherwise the same Roman characters are supported. I guess that would mean once I get a good pretrain performance, I wouldn't need to host separate models nor even pretrain with a mixed corpus, just go straight to my CORD variant training after pretraining in my language. Should work fine with both langs if it's char level. Thank you once again!

Comment: @Gabriel hey, I've ran a couple of experiments, and it turns out the need for pretraining for new non-English characters is a bit overstated! I haven't run another 8-16h training sesh, but tried taking their pretrained cord-v2 as a base without any language-specific pretraining, and the model worked pretty well (around 80% TED-based and 60% F1-based accuracy) with just 150 train samples based off that model, and had no problem with accented/special characters! I'll see how far I can get with more training data (keeps coming in), but it seems like language pretraining is not *that* necessary.

Comment: cord-v2 includes several accented/special characters from french, but if you want better accuracy you still need to pretrain, i got best results after about a week of training on DocSim generated images using my background (i only had 2 different layouts for my documents) and random text added to the same position, basically i've done pretraining and fine tunning simultaneously